# Edit Post Using same form in Flask/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to programming and am working on creating a simple blog with posts and comments. I am having trouble creating an editpost feature using the same form template to add posts. This is my data model for add post:

```
@app.route("/addpost", methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
  title = request.form['title']
  text = request.form['content']
  post = Post(title = title, body = content)
  db.session.add(post)
  db.session.commit()
  return redirect(url_for("posts"))
```

This is currently what I have but I am receiving a Bad Proxy Request.

```
@app.route("/editpost/<int:id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editpost(id):
  title = request.form['title']
  text = request.form['content']

  post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id==id).first()
  post.title = title
  post.body = content
  db.session.commit()
  return redirect(url_for("post", id=id))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What specific problems are you having?

Comment: @dirn I have updated what I am working with right now, but I keep receiving a Bad Request error.

Answer (score 2):

You have an endpoint, `editpost`, that supports both GET and POST requests. The code inside the endpoint, however, assumes a valid POST request. You are receiving a bad request error because of

```
title = request.form['title']
text = request.form['content']
```

The first line is where you get the error, but either line would cause it. `request.form` is populated by the post data in a POST request. When someone submits a GET request (you probably offer a link to the edit page, resulting in the GET), `request.form` does not contain either of these keys. Flask traps the `KeyError` that is raised and replaces it with a `BadRequest`.

There are two things you'll have to do to prevent this from happening. First, you'll only want to do this when the request is a POST. Assuming you want to use the same endpoint and URL to both display the edit form and perform the update, you'll want to include your code inside

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Next, because you probably want to display the form and some error messages when fields are missing, you'll want to be a bit more defensive when accessing the values.

```
title = request.form.get('title')
text = request.form.get('content')
```

Putting it all together:

```
@app.route('/editpost/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def editpost(id):
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id==id).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        text = request.form['content']

        post.title = title
        post.body = content

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('post', id=id))
    else:
        return render_template('something.html', post=post)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am no longer getting the error, but when I replaced something.html with posts.html, it takes me back to the add post page and adds an additional post instead of editing. I do not have a Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's hard to tell you what's wrong with your flow. "posts.html" seems like the page where you list all of your posts. I suspect you'd have a different template for adding/editing posts.